# On login form chrome will save password but with no username

Tags: html, google-chrome, authentication

i am trying to save password with username when loging-in with Google Chrome. But unfortunately the chrome only show password with ( no username ). What seems to be the problem? Here's the image for better imagination.

[image: chrome - no username]

is maybe problem that input of username got name attribute email? (should it be username?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved the problem. First check if your inputs are in form and got name username and password. ( the form must not be generated by JS ).

**Important:**

You can have only ONE input with type="password" per form!

The last one saved my problem. I had two inputs with password type. One was hidden. I changed this hidden input to text type and this done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a hidden input in between the username and password that must have been tricking up Google Chrome:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="login-form">
    <div class="input-box input-left">
      <label for="username">User Name:</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="login[username]" value="" class="required-entry input-text" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-box input-right">
      <label for="login">Password:</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="input-text no-display" name="dummy" id="dummy" />
      <input type="password" id="login" name="login[password]" class="required-entry input-text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Once commenting out that line, with the dummy input, it worked fine.